# Getting last row value using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

Getting java.lang.NullPointerException when i try to get the value of the 
last row in a excel sheet using getLastRowNum() function.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;   
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class Excel{
public static File file;
public static FileInputStream input;
public static FileOutputStream output;
public static HSSFWorkbook book;     
public static HSSFSheet sheet;
public static int value;
public Excel(String path) {


    try {
        file= new File(path);//creating file//
        input=new FileInputStream(file);
        book=new HSSFWorkbook(input);           
        sheet=book.getSheetAt(0);                
        output=new FileOutputStream(file);          
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
        }
public static void readData() {
    int value =sheet.getLastRowNum();//trying to get the last row value//
    System.out.println(value);

}
}
```

Driver class:

```
      public class ExcelTest {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      Excel excel = new Excel("C:/Users/HOME/Desktop/Sample.xlsx");
      Excel.readData();     
}
}
```

Please help on the issue.

Comment: Please show the exact exception you get. Java `Throwable` provides stack traces which contains meaningful information. Please show the stack trace here. To do so, do `...} catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` instead of suppressing the error message. Btw.: `Sample.xlsx` is by it's file name extension not a `HSSFWorkbook` it should rather be a `XSSFWorkbook`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class readExcel {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

              readData("path to sample.xlsx");
    }
    public static void readData(String path) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
            //getting xlsx file from path
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
         XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        //pointing to particlar workbook
            XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            //getting no: of rows
            int value=spreadsheet.getLastRowNum()+1;
            System.out.println("total rows:"+value);

            }

}
```

Please add dom4j-1.6.1,xmlbeans-2.3.0 jars along with the poi-3.9 jar file

Comment: Apache POI 3.9 is ancient! Why are you suggesting code that's [7 years old???](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.9)